# Prove that a certain set is a subgroup of an abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Given that $G$ is a commutative group. Prove that the subset $H = \{a \in G \mid o(a) \operatorname{divides} 10\}$ is a subgroup of $G$.

**My approach**:

Let $\alpha, \beta \in H$. Therefore, $o(\alpha)=k_1$ where $k_1= 1,2,5,10$ and $o(\beta) = k_2$ where $k_2= 1,2,5,10$.

Now, $(\alpha \beta)^{k_1 k_2} = e$, but then $k_1 k_2$ can be equal to $1,2,4,5,10,25,100, \ldots$. So $k_1k_2$ don't divide $10$ .

I am struck here maybe I followed the wrong approach or have misunderstood please if someone can clarify.

Comment: Ever heard of the lcm of two numbers?

Comment: It's true that $(\alpha\beta)^{k_1k_2}=e,$ but the order is the *smallest* such exponent.

Comment: agreed  but then k1k2 necessarily dont divide 10 right? like if I take k1=5 and k2=5 ?

Comment: I don't understand all the downvotes.  I just answered a question entitled "FG-modules V and W isomorphic and its properties" that was considerably more straightforward than this question (it was essentially asking for the proof of a tautology).  Why no downvotes for that but 5 downvotes for a question that can be tricky for a student new to the topic?

Comment: @CMonsour if you know what the lcm of two numbers is then this question is straightforward as well. It is likely that the downvotes sanctioned a lack of personal thoughts and/or rudeness in the comments.

Comment: There is a typo in "$k_1k_2$ don't divide $10$". I guess it should be "doesn't divide", but it might be "$k_1, k_2$ don't divide $10$"...

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Now deleted comments? But then why then downvotes on the answer?!

Comment: @user1729 Yes the comment was flagged and deleted. I guess that downvoting the answer is sending a message to the answerer that it is not necessarily good practice to give complete answers when they think the OP doesn't provide enough efforts and responds to hints by being rude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) $o(e)=1$, which divides $10$, so $e\in H$.

(2) $o(x^{-1})=o(x)$, so if $o(x)$ divides $10$, so does $o(x^{-1})$, so $x\in H$ implies $x^{-1}\in H$

(3) If $x,y\in H$, then $x^{10}=y^{10}=e$, so, since $x$ and $y$ commute, $(xy)^{10}=x^{10}y^{10}=e$, so $o(xy)$ divides $10$, so $xy\in H$.

Thus, $H$ is a subgroup.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I guess this does answer it ! I am trying to mark this is as correct answer but the website is throwing an error that I cant mark this as correct in 4 min , I will mark it correct as soon as this error goes away , thanks again !